# C# Receiving pop3 email with inline images and cid value

Tags: c#, email, pop3, richedit, openpop

I am working to receive pop3 emails via OpenPop component. I am receiving emails from the server and saving to the sql database. At this point, there is no problem.

But today, I realized, some images are not showing on the richtextbox. 
This email's source code :

Original image file name : image001.jpg

> Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image001.jpg"
>       Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>       Content-ID: image001.jpg@01D16A6B.41013C60

And

> In html body, cid value : image001.jpg@01D16A6B.41013C60

With above code, I am not living any problem. Because I am getting image file name from the CID value. (image001.jpg). I am getting image from the SQL server with the true image file name.

But, if we send the same email via Gmail web-interface;

> Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image001.jpg"
>       Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image001.jpg"
>       Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>       Content-ID: ii_iksd5tmd1_152f4c90885b6c5d

And we see on the richtextbox the CID value :

> cid:ii_iksd5tmd1_152f4c90885b6c5d

Here is the problem.

CID value is not contains the file name information. So, I am not getting the image. The CID value is changing when the emails receiving from the Gmail.

In order to catch true image file name, what should I do?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following logic to get the file name:

If the `Content-Disposition` header exists, use the `filename` parameter value as the attachment file name. Otherwise fall back to using the `name` parameter value on the `Content-Type` header if that exists.

The `Content-Id` header value can be anything, all you can really expect from it is that it is a unique string within the context of the message.

Obviously the cid: URL in the HTML of the message refers to the `Content-Id` header value, so if you want to be able to reference the attachment at a later date after saving the attachments to disk, then you'll also need to save the `Content-Id` in the database record for the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Images used inline in HTML Mails do not necessarily have a "true filename". It is possible that they only use the CID. You should store the CID with the images in the database and then retrieve the image via the CID from the database to display it.

Answer (score 0):

OpenPop results :

> Content-Description : null
> Content-ID : null
> Content-Disposition : null

I am trying another web-interface and same results.
For ex : Outlook web-interface

Examples :

> HTML BODY in RichText
>
> "img src="cid:ii_iksd5tlv0_152f4c90885b6c5d" height="398" width="530">
> img src="cid:ii_iksd5tmd1_152f4c90885b6c5d" height="398" width="530">
> ​>

Original image file names : DSC00011.jpg and DSC00018.jpg